# PHP: Set array with specific keys whilst looping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I am looping through, that contains a list of dates.

For each date, I am calling a function within the loop to look up some specific data about that date from a dBase.

I wish to add all of this to an array in the following format:

```
array(
    Date => 2014-04-22,
    array(
        Specific Info 1 => date,
        Specific Info 2 => data,
        Specific Info 3 => data
    )
)
```

and I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

Can I set the key of the array using a variable, instead of 0,1,2,3,4 etc - And can I still do this whilst looping?

`$newArray[]` i know will let me add items to the array on each pass, but I would like to simply specify the Date as the key, with an array within that value.

Comment: Sure, you can specify the date as a key: `$newArray[$date] = "whatever";` works just fine. Watch out for duplicate keys, though. Adding the same key a second time will just overwrite the previous value.

Comment: What do you mean by set key to variable? You can use a variable's data to set a key (ie string or numeric key etc). From what you've said, you want something like `$array[$date] = "specific_info";`

Comment: I can set $array[$date] no problem, but how do I get it so that it was create a new key for each date in the array I am looping through?

Comment: Sound's like you are iterating over an array and trying to modify it's own keys in a single pass - if that's the case it's a risky endeavour and you really want to use a new - empty - array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.

Set $array[$date] = $arrayDetailed;

Cheers :)